# gdate - turn off warnings for invalid dates?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

On `macOS` when using GNU date for an invalid date, like

```
gdate -d "18500229" '+%A %Y%m%d'
```

is there an option I have not found yet to turn off warnings such as `gdate: invalid date ‘18500229’`?

Comment: Would removing all error messages be enough ? If so, adding `2>/dev/null` at the end of your command would work.

Comment: Yes, this works, Aserre! You can write a short answer and I`ll mark it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) I'll link a duplicate question where you can read more about it if you're interested

Comment: The error is most likely `date` is not accepting the provided input date. The year does not have a 29 on the month 02